# Azure Powershell - How to get resource status

Tags: powershell, azure

I have several resources of type Microsoft.ApiManagement/service.

when I use the find cmdlet below with that resource type, it does not return the state/status of the resource.  I can see the state on the portal but am retrieving resource statuses by resource type to get data for a summary dashboard that can be drilled through.  -ResourceType "microsoft.web/sites"
works as expected and displays the state of the resource.

I am not sure if I have to do something else for -ResourceType "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service" to make it display the state.
-ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" does not show the state either though in the portal, Primary:Available, Secondary:Available is displayed.
It seems like each resource type has its set of defined properties and one has to find the documentation to walk that resource type to find what one needs.
I do not know where to find that information.

Thanks!

```
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "microsoft.web/sites"  -ExpandProperties |Sort SiteName
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service"  -ExpandProperties |Sort Name
Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"  -ExpandProperties |Sort Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you could use the following command.

```
$api=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service" -ResourceGroupName shuapi5 -ResourceName shuiapi
$api.Properties.provisioningState
```

I test in my lab, it works for me.

```
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> $api=Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service" -ResourceGroupName shuapi5 -ResourceName shuiapi
PS C:\Users\v-shshui> $api.Properties.provisioningState
Activating
```

Comment: That worked for me as well.  Since we can only get by resource name one at a time, we probably have to set up a loop.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I do have a related question. The API Management Service in the portal has a status that reads 'Online'.  My query for the provisioningState reads "Succeeded'.  How to get the status as seen on the portal?  Thanks

Comment: My bad -- Status Online is for the resource group.  The resource itself has the status "Succeeded" so provisioningState is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a cmdlet that retrieves the nested provisioningState of the resource:  Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceType "microsoft.ApiManagement/service"  -ExpandProperties |Select Name, ResourceGroupName, Location, @{Name='State'; Expression={$_.Properties.ProvisioningState}} | sort Name